# Create 2D Hist with same amount of points in each cell

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a possibility to create a 2D histogram with **irregular** bin sizes with the possibility of plotting heat as the z variable.

The data: I have one billion objects. Every object has the features x, y and an anomaly score of z.

The plot: Plotted are all objects with y against x. The histogram should have irregular (adaptive) bin sizes, so that in every bin created lie the same **amount** of objects. This should initially create a histogram without any visible traits, having just one color (with color representing the count of objects).

To create the bin edges I firstly use np.percentiles and separate the objects based on the x feature into percentiles. Secondly, I use the first x binedge, find all the points within it and bin them in the y direction based on percentiles. That would look something like this (pseudocode):

```
for i, key_x in enumerate(np.percentile(x, np.arange(0,101, 10))):
    xedges[i] = key_x
    objects = find_all_objects_within_binedge(key_x)

    for j, key_y in enumerate(np.percentile(objects["y"], np.arange(0,101, 10))):
        yedges[i, j] = key_y
```

So xedges is an array with the binedges in x direction and yedges is a matrix giving me the y binedges for every x binedge. If this is not understandable please let me know.

So if we imagine the histogram that would result, we would have straight binning lines in x. But in the y direction these lines would be split. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH9eb.png) to get an idea of what I mean with the y bins being irregular split.

And this is were I am stuck. I have no idea how to create a histogram or plot from my x-binedges and y-binedges with these irregular bins.

The goal (for better understanding):
Once that is accomplished, I would like to be able to have each bin colored by the mean or std of all the points within that cell using the z values (have the code for that ready). Ideally this will look very smooth as well, with some minor exceptions, which would be anomalous and what I am looking for. But this should be feasible with plt.pcolormesh.

English is not my native language and I tried my best to describe the problem. If something is unclear please let me know and I'll try to clarify as best as possible. Thank you guys in advance :)

Comment: Is the question how to compute the histogram or how to draw it? Or both?

Comment: I am able to calculate the binedges with the pseudocode and thus define a grid that has the same amount of points in each bin cell. I do not know how to draw the histogram with theses specfific binedges, though.

Comment: I see two possibilities, you draw 10 2D histograms, one for each _x_-bin, or you draw directly the 100 filled rectangles, taking the colours from a colormap. In each case a bit of book keeping is involved, further if you are dealing with a billion records the data processing (binning raw data to compute the _z_-means) is going to be       S     L     O     W

Comment: The 10 histograms is an idea that would actually work and should be quickly implemented. Just the analysis will truly be a pain. How would you go about directly drawing the 100 filled rectangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the question asks for a way to plot values on a grid, which is regular in one dimension, but irregular in the other.
As I understand it such grid would be defined by a 1D array in e.g. x-direction, and a 2D array in y-direction. Both arrays would denote the edges of the grid cells in the respective dimension.

For a M x N grid, `x_edges` would hence have `N+1` elements, and `y_edges` would be of shape `(M+1, N)`. The following would be a 4 x 3 grid.

```
x_edges = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y_edges = np.array([[0.,0.,0.],
                    [.3,.2,.2],
                    [.5,.6,.4],
                    [.8,.9,.7],
                    [1.,1.,1.]])
```

The usual matplotlib tools like `imshow` or `pcolor` do - as far as I can see - not allow to plot such grids. An alternative is hence to use a `PolyCollection` and plot the respective rectangles with it.

An array of values that shall be mapped to color can be set to that collection. This array should have one value less per dimension and be flat, i.e. have M*N elements.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

# Starting data: A grid, regular in x-direction and irregular in y direction.
x_edges = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y_edges = np.array([[0.,0.,0.],
                    [.3,.2,.2],
                    [.5,.6,.4],
                    [.8,.9,.7],
                    [1.,1.,1.]])

######## Grid creation ################
#y_edges = np.concatenate((y_edges, np.zeros(len(y_edges))))
s = np.array(y_edges.shape)
# make x_edges 2D as well.
x_edges = np.tile(x_edges, s[0]-1).reshape((s[0]-1, s[1]+1))

# you may also have an array of values. 
# This should be of shape one less than the edges and flattened.
values = np.arange(np.prod(s+np.array((-1,0))))

# Produce a vertices array of the edges of rectangles that form each pixel.
x = np.c_[x_edges[:,:-1].flatten(), x_edges[:,:-1].flatten(),
          x_edges[:,1: ].flatten(), x_edges[:,1: ].flatten()]
y = np.c_[y_edges[:-1,:].flatten(), y_edges[1: ,:].flatten(),
          y_edges[1: ,:].flatten(), y_edges[:-1,:].flatten()]
xy = np.stack((x,y), axis=2)

# Create collection of rectangles.
pc = PolyCollection(xy, closed=True, edgecolors="k", linewidth=0.72, cmap="inferno")
pc.set_array(values)

######## Plotting ################
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(pc)
fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax)

ax.margins(0)
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

[image]

This grid uses a small number of cells to show the principle. If you want to have more cells, make sure not to plot the edges of rectangles by removing the `edgecolors` and `linewidth` arguments.

Comment: This is precisely what I need, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want the data to be binned based on equal amounts of data in the bin. Indeed percentiles can be used for this purpose. If you use numpy you can do this along d dimensions. Here is an example for 2d binning:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array, random, percentile

data = random.randn(1000, 2)
data[:, 1] = data[:, 1] * .1 + 1 # shift the gauss


percentiles = percentile(data, range(0, 100, 10), axis = 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(*data.T, bins = percentiles.T)
fig.show()
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Edit:
non-uniform grid example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
data = random.randn(1000, 2)
data[:, 1] = data[:, 1] * .1 + 1 # shift the gauss

xper = percentile(data[:, 0], range(0, 101, 10))
yper = zeros((xper.size, xper.size))

binnedData = ones(yper.shape)
for index, (binstart, binend) in enumerate(zip(xper[:-1], xper[1:])):
    idx = where(logical_and(data[:, 0] >= binstart, data[:, 0] <= binend))[0] # expensive
    yper[index] = percentile(data[idx, 1], range(0, 101, 10))
    for jndex, j in  enumerate(digitize(data[idx, 1], yper[index])):
        j -= 1 #digit takes right bins
        # generate dummy values
        binnedData[index, j] += data[idx[j], :].sum() /  xper.size
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(xper, yper, binnedData)
```

[image: non uni]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
"From what I understand you want the data to be binned based on equal amounts of data in the bin. " That is correct.
Judging from your histogram and code, I assume that the color is the amount of points in each bin. If so that means that each bin holds a different amount of data points. If each bin truly had an equal amount of data points than the entire hist would have a single color. That is what I am looking for. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Did some quick check for your code: What your code does is that it calculates the percentiles of each dimension individually. Thus if you use the generated bin edges you will see distortions in the amount of data like in your graph. Its a good approximation that I have currently implemented. 
What I need, though, is a method to create and plot binsizes that takes both dimension simultaneously into account. Creating the binedges is describe in my code example. But I am lost in plotting it. Throws a TypeError since I use an array and a matrix for my bins.

Comment: It is true that in my code the counts are somewhat uneven, but if you look at the count data they are very close to one another. The colors seem more dramatic than they in reality are. Based on your extended description you want the bins to be for every x and then bin again for the ys associated with those x?

Comment: Yes, you have the idea what I need. That is already done by the pseudocode. The problem is plotting the whole thing. 
With your code the deviations are very small due to the RV being drawn from a normal distribution. I have a dataset of galactic objects with partially terrible spread that I can only slightly compensate for through scaling and log-transforms. Due to that the problem of the uneven distribution becomes severe... But at the same time plotting the std as the heat should give obvious results.

Comment: I may be wrong but this will be difficult to plot. One way may be to 'copy' the xedges along the yedges and use pcolormesh to plot it. I updated the example. Another way would be to extrapolate the data to a regular grid and plot those. But From what I gather that option is not really preferred.